# How to detect JNI calls from smali code?

Tags: disassembly, android, java

In Android, JNI calls could be used to load native code from other sources. From the link http://bobao.360.cn/learning/detail/3765.html, the following sample code shows how a smali code would look like when calling the function "decryptString" from a native library.

```
const/16 v3, 0x57
new-array v1, v3, [B
fill-array-data v1, :array_2a
.local v1, "encryptedStringBytes":[B
invoke-static {}, Lorg/cf/nativeharness/Cryptor;->getInstance()Lorg/cf/nativeharness/Cryptor;
move-result-object v0
.line 21
.local v0, "c":Lorg/cf/nativeharness/Cryptor;
# v3 contains a String made from encrypted bytes
new-instance v3, Ljava/lang/String;
invoke-direct {v3, v1}, Ljava/lang/String;-><init>([B)V
# Call the decryption method, move result back to v3
invoke-virtual {v0, v3}, Lorg/cf/nativeharness/Cryptor;->decryptString(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
move-result-object v3
```

The original java code would look something like this:

```
public class Cryptor {
    private static Cryptor instance = null;
    public static Cryptor getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new Cryptor();
        }
        return instance;
    }
    public native String decryptString(String encryptedString);
}
```

There seems to be no indication from the smali code that a native code is being loaded. What "signatures" in a smali code would be a good indicator that JNI calls are being made from the original java code?

Answer (score 6):

You want to look at the definitions of the methods being called. The definition of the `decryptString` method will contain the `native` access flag, similar to it's corresponding java declaration. e.g. Something like:

```
.method public native decryptString(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String
```

Additionally, you can look for calls to `System.loadLibrary` as an indication that the application is loading a library in order to perform JNI calls.